# Candy Box 2- Spell Trouble

Tags: candy-box-2

I have recently gathered a bunch of spells, but I am afraid to test them out and use them because I am a rather big horder in games and I am afraid that you can only use each spell once. Can you only use it once in the whole game, or once each battle? Please answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use each spell more than once.

After you cast a spell, you need to wait several seconds until you can cast another. This wait time can be reduced by

> Giving Pains au Chocolat to the wishing well.